# installing popcorn-time.se on linux kali 2.0

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I have downloaded [popcorntime.io](http://popcorntime.io) fork and built it from source and it's working fine, but I really need the other version found here [popcorn-time.se](http://popcorn-time.se/). I'm finding it rather difficult to do, since I can't do  `./configure && make && make install`, can someone please guide me through the process of installing it properly?

Comment: Repeat after me: "**Kali Linux Is A Penetration Testing Tool, Not Suitable For Actual Desktop Use**"

Comment: I know , and it's been amazing at doing this , by my question I mean to say that there has to be a way of doing it since it's a linux distro

Comment: Yes there is, and that way boils down to "turn your Kali Linux install into something vaguely resembling an actual desktop system - as envisioned by H.P. Lovecraft and drawn by Picasso." It's *technically* possible much in the same way it's technically possible to build a bike out of corroded sheet iron, duct tape and rubber tree sap, but anyone sane will tell you to *just get an actual bike instead*.

Comment: To wit, in order to, as you call it -- and the fact that that's what you call it tells me you don't have the vaguest clue what you're doing -- "`./configure && make && make install`", you'd have to install and set up a full compiler and build suite on a system that lacks both of those *and does not have package management capabilities to easily install them*. There's a chicken and egg problem there and you don't have the ability to work your way through them or we wouldn't be having this discussion.

Comment: @Shadur I appreciate your help , but why do I get the feeling that you're fuming about this question ?

Comment: Take a good look at all the utter noob questions tagged [kali-linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) on this site, far too many of which boil down to "I'm trying to use a specialized penetration testing tool as a desktop OS and it doesn't work right, help!" and you might get an inkling.

Comment: @Shadur what do you recommend then ?

Comment: Install a real desktop-purpose distribution. *any* desktop-purpose distribution. Remember, just because you *can* use a surgical scalpel or a chainsaw to cut meat doesn't mean that either of them are really the best idea to put next to your plate at dinner.